# Loop in a non-uniform magnetic field with downward force

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields

Imagine a circular wire loop of radius R carrying current I, suspended above a current carrying solenoid in the non-uniform magnetic field of the solenoid. 
Here, $\vec{B}$ has a radial component as the magnetic field, to a good approximation, radiates spherically.

[image]

It is claimed there is a downward force on the loop.

Why is this so? What is happening?

Comment: The 'suspended loop' is depicted with the letter "I" and an arrow.  Why?  Also, you speak of 'nonuniform magnetic field'; could this be a time-dependent (changing) magnetic field?

Comment: @Whit3rd
Page 273
http://117.55.241.6/library/E-Books/Electromagnetics%20by%20Griffiths.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Parallel currents attract.   The solenoid, with current in the direction shown, has current parallel to that in the loop, and the  loop will be attracted to the solenoid.   A uniform B field, however, would put no net force on such a loop; any force on one section of the loop would be cancelled by equal and opposite force on 
another section of the loop (the opposite side of the loop carrying the same
current in the opposite direction).

The radial (radiating as if it were coming from a point in the center) B field
component is not uniform (it's strong in the center, and points in various
directions).  That part of the B field puts a net force on the current-carrying ring.